# How to combine multiple Pattern for match?

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I want to match files with extensions `*.md` and `*.tex` in `posts` directory.

The reason I can't use `"posts/*" :: Pattern` is because there are files `*.tex.metadata` in the posts directory. And `site` will give error on that files.

```
[ERROR] Hakyll.Web.readPandocWith: I don't know how to read a file of the type Binary for: posts/2017-06-02-tex.metadata
```

Try following code and fail with empty match (no html output).

```
match (fromList ["posts/*.md", "posts/*.tex"]) $ do
    route $ setExtension "html"
    compile $ pandocCompiler

let postFiles :: Pattern
    postFiles = fromGlob "posts/*.md" `mappend` fromGlob "posts/*.tex"

match postFiles $ do
    route $ setExtension "html"
    compile $ pandocCompiler
```

Maybe I should use `fromRegex` but I have no idea how to write regex for that.

Addition learning resource is very much welcome. The [documentation](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Identifier-Pattern.html) is lack of sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let postFiles :: Pattern
    postFiles = fromGlob "posts/*.md" .||. fromGlob "posts/*.tex"

match postFiles $ do
    route $ setExtension "html"
    compile $ pandocCompiler
```

you can read "Composing patterns" from [documentation](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Identifier-Pattern.html)
what different functions there are to compose multiple `Pattern` values.

`pattern1 .||. pattern2` creates a pattern, that matches if `pattern1` or `pattern2` or both matches (this is what you want).

`pattern1 .&&. pattern2` creates a pattern that matches, if `pattern1` and `pattern2` match (you don't want this but it illustrates what can be done, too).